# use of PTR during label assignment x86

Tags: assembly, x86, ida

So I've disassembled a small c++ program (learning a lot more about assembly since I've started this) and one of the first things that the assembly does at the top of the main procedure is

```
var_E4= byte ptr -0E4h
```

I know that ptr is used to declare the size of data the assembler can't implicitly know but after a lot of looking around I haven't found an example or explanation of this particular setup.  Is the byte ptr telling the assembler to assign -228 to var_E4 (essentially telling to treat it as a single signed hex value)?  If not what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a macro definition that lets it write `[rsp + var_E4]` instead of `[rsp - 0E4h]`, to help improve the readability of the disassembly output for instructions that are accessing local variables on the stack.

You didn't tell us which disassembler exactly you used, or give any context (like lines that use this macro).  I think there's probably not much more to say, though.  Writing it this way vs. substituting in the value everywhere the macro is used has zero effect on the binary machine code you'd get from assembling.

Comment: I used Ida pro and a line similar to this (only the hex value and label differ) is the first line of every procedure so I know it's reserving space on the stack for the procedure I was just curious about byte ptr in this context since I couldn't find anything about it anywhere else.  thanks for the tip on what to include with future questions about disassembley and x86

Comment: @James: Oh right, I didn't mouseover that IDA tag to see what it was.  This line isn't doing *anything*.  Space is reserved on the stack with a `sub rsp, some_number`.  The line you posted just makes a symbolic name for the offset.  Like I said, purely source-level sugar.